# How to find optimal sweet spot for time-space trade-off?

Tags: runtime-analysis

If an algorithm can solve a problem in X iterations using Y bytes of space, then another algorithm that solves it in less bytes than Y, will usually end up needing to do it in more iterations (or time) than X.

One can keep increasing the space/memory to reduce the cycles or cpu time, but will eventually get cursed by something, I guess cost of purchasing all that memory.

On the other hand, one may go the opposite direction and suffer increase CPU time.

In other words, on one end we face time (more cpu cycles means more waiting), and on the opposite end we face the cost of space (e.g. RAM price).

This means that the time-space can be seen as a possibility convex-like curve if we view it as the time-space/cost perspective.  So I guess the sweet-spot is the middle hanging point under convex's belly.

**My question is:** what is done in this regard to make this chart more convex-like?  Because as soon as we do it we can know sweetpoint in the trade offs option.

Comment: I don't know of any reason to assume that the tradeoff curve must be convex.  I'm not sure what you mean by "convex-like", "hanging point under convex's belly", "more convex-like"; those sound pretty vague to me.  Usually when you have a tradeoff between multiple objectives there is no clear way to select a particular tradeoff without more context, so I don't think you're going to find what you are hoping for.

Comment: Ever heard of key derivation functions?  Basically they are memory-hard problems.  If you go to the left by trying to solve them using fewer CPU cycles, you'd need a lot of RAM (hence cost bites here).  If you go to the right to use little RAM instead, CPU cycles increase exponentially (hence cost bites there again).  So I'd imagine that the cost looks like a convex-like shape, with cost going up on left and right, but lowest somewhere in the middle.  Is this clear?  Or should I elaborate more?